# Remove a Package which has faulty dependencies/postinstall scripts

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

Assume I have a fresh new instalation of ubuntu.
I decided (or I had) to install a package using `apt-get`.

```
 wget -q -O- http://apt.nuxeo.org/nuxeo.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

Importing the key

```
 sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://apt.nuxeo.org/ $(lsb_release -cs) releases"
 sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://apt.nuxeo.org/ $(lsb_release -cs) fasttracks"
```

Adding the repositories

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install nuxeo
```

The installation fails because a lazy developer forgot to add a dependency/or other reasons.<sub>(I skimmed the part which adviced me to install Java 1.8)</sub>

And now we are stuck with an incomplete instalation. (Which repeteadly tries to install everytime I try to do something related with apt-get (purge, remove, install))

When I try to use `apt-get purge`, `apt-get` keeps retrying to install incomplete instalation so I cannot manage to remove it. And when trying to install the dependency which relies on (Java 1.8), dpkg seems to refuse to install, apparently because of the previous error.

[This](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15262888/) is a summary of what happens when I type `sudo apt-get --force-yes remove nuxeo`
As you can see the initscript fails because not all dependencies are matched. (Which should not matter because I'm trying to **remove** it!)

When met with a package like this what can one do to remove it completely?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `autoclean`:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

You can also try force removal (**use with caution**):

```
sudo apt-get --force-yes remove package_name
```

Comment: I believe autoclean, justs removes orphaned dependencies.
For the second command, I've updated the question to clarify.

Comment: There are a couple more things that you can do using the terminal but I am guessing you might have already tried all of those. Did you try using the synaptic manager?